# How to decrease tests running time with Jest?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I'm running 60 E2E tests with Jest and Puppeteer on an EC2 Jenkins slave. Tests' times ranging between 7-90 seconds, averaged at 24 seconds - meaning total time when running sequentially ~24-25 min.
When running `jest -w 10` it runs 10 tests in parallel but every test takes longer and the time is resembles `jest --runInBand` both finish at about 24-26 min.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864793/why-does-jest-runinband-speed-up-tests/44506948) and related links, and so changed the machine I'm running on to `r5ad.12xlarge` (48 cores, 384 GB!) because of the assumption of limited resources and still no effect on the total running time. More attempts I made:

- Tried with and without `--ci --detectOpenHandles`, still nothing.
- `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` didn't change it either.
- Ran with default, 2, 3, 9, 15... workers.
- Checked heap usage with `node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage` and saw some leak - heap usage gradually increased from ~100MB to 1100MB
- Tried running locally on the machine (without Jenkins restrictions on resources if any...)

My question is if I'm missing something (a flag, Jenkins agent policy)? Maybe I should try a different test runner for the purpose of E2E because jest is aimed more at unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple more attempts, I figured out the main problems:

1. There's a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41929) in Jenkins when you update the `defaultValue` in pipeline it only takes effect after another build. So removing `--detectOpenHandles` made my build long even after removing it. Plus, it made the results were hard to follow.
2. Jest really depends on the number of cores available, so I changed the machine to a `c5.4xlarge` with 16 vCPUs and that also made a big difference. My fine tune was to set `--maxWorkers=33%` because our web app also runs on the same machine.

Hope this helps someone.